PHP HTTPOnly cookies and how it does affect on sessions
If using PHP HTTPOnly cookies, how does it affect on sessions when a PHP script is executed by jQuery/Ajax?
I mean that will the sessions still work while the cookie cannot be modified?
Or does using HTTPOnly mean that when running a script by jQuery/Ajax, all sessions will remain the same and they cannot be modified at all?


Using HTTPOnly cookies ensures that session cookies are protected from client-side access, thereby enhancing security. It does not interfere with the functioning of sessions in PHP when scripts are executed by jQuery/Ajax. The session data remains accessible and modifiable by the server, while the client-side code cannot tamper with the session cookie.


By the way, does HTTPOnly prevent jQuery/Ajax call from modifying cookies?

@xms it prevents JavaScript from reading or manipulating the cookie value. The cookie will still automatically be send back to the server, when you make an HTTP request via AJAX/fetch, and new cookies received in an HTTP response, will still be accepted by the client.

@CBroe Do you mean that jQuery/Ajax is alloved to modify cookies when using HTTPOnly, but JavaScript is not allowed to do it?

@xms jQuery/AJAX are JavaScript. Neither of them is allowed to read or modify a  HTTPOnly cookie. It will be send automatically with HTTP requests you make via JavaScript though.
